# Where can I find the language variants of Typed Racket?

Tags: typed-racket

The 2017 Typed Racket POPL Paper, ["Type Systems as Macros"](https://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/stchang/pubs/ckg-popl2017.pdf) says that there are several alternative Typed Rackets: for example, typed rackets that do and do not have subtyping. Each sub-language is represented by a color in Table 1 on Page 8:

[image]

Where can I find and experiment with these language variants?

I am not seeing them in [The Typed Racket Guide](http://web.mit.edu/racket_v612/amd64_ubuntu1404/racket/doc/ts-guide/index.html) nor in [the repo](https://github.com/racket/typed-racket).

Comment: I believe they're in the attached artifact webpage (see instructions there): https://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/stchang/popl2017/

Comment: @AtharvaShukla could you copy this to an answer so I can mark it correct–exactly what I was looking for, and I just checked - all code examples from the paper are adapted and executable in the VM.